# SVG gets blurry when scaled up in ImageView (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, svg, imageview, scaling

I'm trying to add a SVG image to an AppCompatImageView. The image should be the fullscreen background of my application. It is a very wide image that should be scaled up to the device's screen height. The width of the image is simply cut based on the device's screen width.
The problem I'm facing is that the SVG image gets blurry and pixelated when it is scaled up, which shouldn't happen since it's an SVG.

Basic setup

- Android project with minSdkVersion 21
- SVG should be loaded in an AndroidX `AppCompatImageView` within a ConstraintLayout
- The SVG is located in the drawable folder and is set directly in the xml layout file via `app:srcCompat`
- `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` is enabled in app Gradle

I've tried multiple different SVG images to rule out the possibility that my SVG was broken. I tried different options for converting the SVG to a VectorDrawable including the Android Studio's Vector Asset Studio and multiple external convertors.
I even tried subclassing the AppCompatImageView and do the scaling manually with scaleType matrix, calculating the scaling factor based on the screen size and apply the scaling matrix to the drawable.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/background"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,651:160"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Expected behaviour would be that the SVG image scales up without any major quality loss. The actual behaviour is that it gets pixelated and blurry.

Comment: Android Studio's Vector Drawable is not real vector. It converts to PNG at build time and use the PNG as resource. So it is not strange they are blurry.

Comment: As far as I understood it, pngs are only generated for api versions prior to 21 since svg support is only available for 21 and up. Since I'm on 21, that shouldn't be the problem. The generated folder ```app/build/generatedres/pngs``` is empty after building the project, so no pngs are generated. That's the whole point of svgs, right?